# Undefined variable: products (View: /projects/ProjectWebsite/resources/views/shop/index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

please can someone help, This is my model that i have created

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['imagePath', 'title', 'description', 'price'];
}
```

this is the blade file

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')

Checkouts Page

@endsection

@section('content')

@foreach($products->chunk(3) as $productChunk)

<div class="row">

@foreach($productChunk as $product)

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="" height="200" width="300"> 
<div class="caption">
<h3></h3>
<p class="description"> </p>

 <div class="clearfix">
 <div class="pull-left price"></div>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Add to Basket</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>


@endforeach
</div>

@endforeach

@endsection
```

this is the error i have got : Undefined variable: products (View: /projects/ProjectWebsite/resources/views/shop/index.blade.php)

this is the controller (edit) forgot to add first time i posted

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller

{
      public function getIndex()
    {


         $products = Product::all();        
         return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products]);

    }

 }
```

this is the route i have set up
     Route::get('/', 'ProductController@getIndex');

Comment: Could you share the controller function with us?

Comment: Please, put it in your question ;)

Comment: Haha sorry have done

Comment: Nice, thanks. So to be clear: You posted the blade code from `shop.index.blade.php`? And you are using a route that loads `ProductController@getIndex`?

Comment: yes should I upload the route?

Comment: Might be nice to add as 'proof' that it is setup ok :)

Comment: i have uploaded the route at the end

Comment: As far as I can tell, your route points to correct controller-function, your controller-function passes the variable to the correct view, but the view does not recognize the passed variable. Is it possible that the code you are actually running, is not the code you see? Like maybe it has been cached? You could try `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan view:clear` to clear those, even tho I dont think the last one could help in this case.

Comment: hi thank you so much. That was it, it's working. I was confused as it was working before and I thought I somehow messed the code up but it looks like it had been cached. Thanks it's working now